# 500 internal server error on WebLogic server

Tags: java, spring, weblogic, struts

when I pass more than 1000 param I'm getting 500 internal server error on WebLogic server. Please suggest me any configuration have to be changed or any other. When I execute in tomcat setting max parameter attribute that issue getting resolved. But I need a solution in Weblogic server.Please help me

Answer (score 0):

First result in google:

https://community.oracle.com/thread/4044784

Configure it by setting a higher value in MaxRequestParameterCount.

It would be helpful to know your WebLogic version, error message, etc.